# JQuery, Insert Text into a TextBox

Tags: jquery, textbox

Let's say I have a TextBox with the value `1000000`.  How can I add a period following the `1`, so that the output is `1.000000`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var input = $('#yourId');
var text = input.val();
input.val(text.substring(0, 1) + '.' + text.substring(1));
```

[Fiddle answer](https://jsfiddle.net/kingleroyg/b9vwy78j/1/)